# Applying Ripple to a DC Source?

Tags: batteries, bias, test, ripple

I have a system that is powered by a 25V Lithium ion battery pack. I need to test the system with a 1 Vpp sine applied on top of the 25V supply, so 25V +/- 0.5V ripple.

1. I know theoretically to get this signal I could use a function generator generating a sine wave and feed that through a series capacitor, but is having an AC signal applied this way bad for the battery?
2. Can I put a large inductance between the battery and the capacitor such that none (or very little) of the AC voltage is seen at the battery?
3. Does the function generator need to be able to source much current?

The system may pull 1 to 2 amps maximum.

Comment: What frequency must the ripple be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q: Can I put a large inductance between the battery and the capacitor such that none (or very little) of the AC voltage is seen at the battery?

A: Yes, that is the way to go

Q: Does the function generator need to be able to source much current?

A: that depends on the AC input impedance of your equipment under test. (You can test it: The function generator will not get damaged)